# Applying the Galvin-Hajnal Theorem?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Working my way through chapter 24 of Jech's *Set Theory*, but progress is painfully slow. I'm now stuck on question 24.3:

> If $2^{\aleph_{\alpha}}\leq\aleph_{\alpha+2}$ holds for all cardinals of cofinality $\omega$, then the same holds for all singular cardinals.

It seems like the proof should be similar to that of Theorems 8.12 and/or 8.13, but quite frankly I'm utterly lost. Any hints?

Comment: Recall the proof of Silver's theorem, the behavior at singular cardinals with uncountable cofinality is determined on a stationary subset, and the cardinals with countable cofinality make such stationary subset.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I'll repeat my recommendation from MathOverflow. If you want to learn more about PCF or about Galvin-Hajnal, then Jech is not the place for either. For PCF you could read the chapter in the Handbook of Set Theory by Abraham-Magidor, both are excellent writers (and teachers!); for the Galvin-Hajnal part I can recommend "Introduction to Cardinal Arithmetic", written by three guys Holtz, et al.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Please consider upgrading your comment to an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 4):

Converting my comment to an answer:

> Recall the proof of Silver's theorem, the behavior at singular cardinals with uncountable cofinality is determined on a stationary subset, and the cardinals with countable cofinality make such stationary subset.

Comment: (I've made it CW for the same reason it was a comment to begin with: I don't feel that I can fully answer the question without working through it completely myself, and I don't have the time. That's just a vague recollection of why things should work one way or another.)